# android studio pick python file in file picker

Tags: android, python-3.x, android-studio, chaquopy

is there a way in android studio to make the ak pick python file using the file picker and read and show it on the screen something like edit text?

This is the code i am using when doing so

```java
    private void filePicker(){

         //Now permission working
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File picker call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //Let's pick file
        Intent opengallery=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        opengallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

         //setting the type
        opengallery.setType("*/*"); 
        startActivityForResult(opengallery,REQUEST_FILE);
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_FILE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String filePath=getRealPathFromUri(data.getData(), MainActivity.this);
            Log.d("File Path:", " "+filePath);
        }
    }
    public String getRealPathFromUri (Uri contentUri, Activity activity) {
        String path = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
```

I want to pick python file among the many files present in the file explorer of phone. so i can upload it in my android studio application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My god.. why do you call that filepicker. You are using ACTION_GET_CONTENT. And not in Android Studio but in your Android app. And python file? Name the extension!

Comment: You do not need any permission using ACTION_GET_CONTENT. So please remove all that permission code. And rephrase your post.

Comment: so what is your problem? too many files to choose from? or .py file is not listed? or you found the .py file but unable  to get the content? or when you choose .py file, it crashed? or you get corrupted content? "I can not get proper solution" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The .py file is not listed and i want  the file to be read and shown on the screen